# MYSQL employee working hours for each day in date range

Tags: mysql, date-range, days

Hi I have a MySQL query that looks into a table that holds hours for each day the employee work. My query looks at the day of the date and the result is what hours we worked. so let say 2015-11-24 is Tuesday then 8.

How do I run the query without PHP to look at every day in a date range?
Thanks

```
Eg. $holidaystart = '2015-11-24';
    $holidayend = '2015-11-30';

    #Table employees hours   id   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu  Fri  Sat  Sun
                             1    8     8     0     8    8    8    0

                $sql= "select  empId,
            '".$holidayStart."' as date,
            case dayname('".$holidayStart."')
                when 'Sunday' then Sun
                when 'Monday' then Mon
                when 'Tuesday' then Tue
                when 'Wednesday' then Wed
                when 'Thursday' then Thu
                when 'Friday' then Fri
                when 'Saturday' then Sat
            else 0 end as hours
            from employees"  ;
```

Edit

I have one table that  holds employee id number (empId) Then each day of the week Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| empid   |  Mon  |  Tue  | Wed  |  Thu | Fri  |  Sat | Sun  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   1     |   8   |   8   |  0   |   8  |  8   |   8  |   0  |
|   2         0       8   |  8       0  |  8   |   8  |   8  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

so employee 1 as a working shift of 8 hour on Mon, 8 on Tue,  0 Wed, 8 Thu, 8 Fri, 8 Sat 0 Sunday . So what I am trying to achieve  is to  look at lets say 2015-11-24 to 2015-11- 26 and see how many hours are employee 1 will work between the 2 date based on how many hours they are suppose to work in each day Mon = 8 hour shift Tue = 8 hour shift Wed = 0 (day off) Thu = 8 Fri = 8 Sat = 8 Sun day off

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1854/2)

As you can see  by the demo 2015-10-10 is saturday so empId 1 = 8 hours empId 2 = 6 hours and empId 3 = 8 hours so how do i do this using a date range?

Comment: @RubahMalam Any Ideas?

Comment: DESCRIBE employees; pls

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'without PHP'. There's clearly some PHP there ?!?!

Comment: The employeeas just the id of the employee followed by each day in the week then the hours they work for each day eg. check the date 2015-11-15 then the result is wed =0 hours

Comment: At the moment I use php to run through each day in the date range while (strtotime($holidayStart) <= strtotime($holidayEnd)) {} would like it to just use MySQL

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. Certainly better than anything we could come up with in MySQL

Comment: @Muhammad Muazzam Whats pivot explain please?

Comment: @jonathanyoung - MySQL doesn't have pivoting functions anyway, so that isn't terribly helpful.  My answer basically does a pivot (turns rows into columns) without the pivoting functions that some other databases have natively.

Comment: does this table design imply that your employees are employed only for 1 week? how do you handle a 2+ week employee?

Comment: I have setup a fiddle demo of my database  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1854/2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has the following columns:

```
empId - Employee id
workDate - the date they worked
hoursWorked - the number of hours they worked that day
```

Then something like this

```
SELECT empId
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Sunday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Sun,
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Monday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Mon,
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Tuesday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Tues,
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Wednesday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Wed,
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Thursday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Thurs,
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Friday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Fri,
   SUM(IF(dayname(workDate) = 'Saturday', hoursWorked, 0)) As Sat,
FROM employees
GROUP BY empId
WHERE workDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

Don't forget to use prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection!

Comment: The work date is not stored in a table. What I am doing is check the amount of hours between 2 date. eg 2015-11-24 to 2015-11-26 result would be empid =1  2015-11-24 Wed '0' 2015-11-25 Thu '8' 2015-11-26 Fri '8' so the count would be '16'

Comment: @jonathanyoung - can you please post the schema for your table?  That would take the guesswork out of this.

Comment: Petroejie I have setup a fiddle demo of how my database works 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1854/2

Comment: @jonathanyoung - I think I understand it now, but in order to do this purely in MySQL you would need to have a table containing all possible dates.  In some other databases you could avoid that using a recursive CTE, but MySQL doesn't have those.

Comment: Ok Eric was thinking of sending the data to temp table?

Comment: I have but the hoiidays into a table how do I query it against the holiday table and public holiday table I have in my Fiddle demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab629/1. The temp table will check to see how many holidays are left in that year. Then if a minus figure in the year stop the insert into the holiday table Thanks for your help a little stuck!

Comment: Would like a column with teamp hours and a column with holiday temp days along side the columns I have!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a blind shot, because you haven't provided us with the structure of table employees. Try to following:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE `date` BETWEEN ".$startDate.'" AND "'.$endDate.'"');
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $arr[$row[date]]=$row;
}
$totalHours=0;
for($i=strtotime($startDate);$i<=strtotime($endDate);$i+=86400){
$day=$arr[date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$i];
if($day){
$id=$day[id];
}
$hours=($day)? $day[hours] : 0;
$totalHours+=$hours;
echo "Employee $id Day ".date('D',$i). " Hours $hours";
}
echo "Total hours $totalHours";
```

You shouldn't use the mysql library and instead use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You need the part that accounts for missing dates.

Comment: Still you can do it in PHP, instead of being violent against the poor SQL server.

Comment: I know, but by omitting it, you're not really contributing much to this problem (as i see it)

Comment: This should do the job. If any questions feel free to ask

Comment: Well this query won't do you any good, for sure. You need a date field, otherwise with this table it's impossible to understand the date on which the employee logged in any hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dynamic Pivot query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT empId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(case dayname(table_date_field)
                when 'Sunday' then Sun
                when 'Monday' then Mon
                when 'Tuesday' then Tue
                when 'Wednesday' then Wed
                when 'Thursday' then Thu
                when 'Friday' then Fri
                when 'Saturday' then Sat
            else 0 end as hours
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM employees;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT empId,', @sql, ' FROM employees GROUP BY empId');
```